# compiler optimisation when returning strings

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

If I have

```
private string Foo(string decrypted)
{
    return decrypted.Substring(blah);
}
```

and

```
private string Foo(string decrypted)
{
    string s = decrypted.Substring(blah);
    return s;
}
```

Is this the same? Is the compiler able to remove `s`?

How about

```
private string Foo(string decrypted)
{
    string s = decrypted.Substring(blah);
    string t = s;
    return t;
}
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter? `string` is a reference type, so even if it wasn't optimized it would at worst be two additional word-sized copies. That's peanuts.

Comment: it doesn't matter,
it is O(1) time difference
The first is normally more readable, so use that.
Except when the second is more readable, then use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the question is basically "does the C# compiler support [named return value optimization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/02/03/66739.aspx) (NRVO)?"

That's a reasonable question, I suppose, but like [delnan points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044817/compiler-optimisation-when-returning-strings#comment24641711_17044817), it's not particularly relevant because of the fact that strings in C# are reference types. If you're a C++ programmer, you can think of reference types as essentially equivalent to pointers. So although you are returning the string by value, you're really only returning the *reference* by value, not the object itself. It's just as if you were returning the pointer address by value. A copy of the entire string object need not be made, so the optimization gains you very little. The only reason you need NRVO is to avoid suffering the performance hit of a large and expensive copy, but copying a pointer/reference is not expensive.

However, if you had given a different example that used a value type rather than a reference type (e.g., a large structure), then there might be a significant performance improvement to be gained by implementing NRVO. Unfortunately, even in this case, I do not believe that the C# compiler does this. I suppose the JITer might; I can't say for sure. (And if it isn't done now, it could always be added in future versions. Although such large structures are found only rarely in C# code, so it's unlikely this is at the top of the performance team's list of goals.)

For more details, Jon Skeet's article on [References and Values](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html) in C# is recommended reading.

Answer (score 4):

I was curious, so I tried it out (using LINQPad 4 with optimizations). This is what I got:

```
private string Foo(string decrypted)
{
    return decrypted.Substring(0);
}
Foo:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  callvirt    System.String.Substring
IL_0007:  ret        

private string Foo(string decrypted)
{
    string s = decrypted.Substring(0);
    return s;
}
Foo:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  callvirt    System.String.Substring
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // s
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_0009:  ret     

private string Foo(string decrypted)
{
    string s = decrypted.Substring(0);
    string t = s;
    return t;
}
Foo:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  callvirt    System.String.Substring
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // s
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_0009:  stloc.1     // t
IL_000A:  ldloc.1     // t
IL_000B:  ret
```

It appears the compiler doesn't optimize away `s` or `t`, however, I suspect the JIT interpreter would.

Comment: Is that from release mode with optimisations? (debug mode will definitely leave them in)

Comment: @viraptor I turned on optimizations within LINQPad, yes. According to LINQPad, it's "equivalent to Visual Studio's 'Release' mode and disables live execution tracking"

Comment: Release builds from Visual Studio *definitely* remove the extra variable. (I just tested it) So it seems that what Linqpad says isn't true. In Reflector it just shows: `return decrypted.Substring(0);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson good to know. LINQPad uses the [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://www.linqpad.net/HowLINQPadWorks.aspx) so CSC must be doing something more that LINQPad doesn't. Could you post the IL you see for comparison?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I just saw my mistake: I was looking at the C# view in Reflector, and it hides the additional locals to just show `return decrypted.Substring(0);` as I said - but when I look at the IL I can see the extra locals. So Reflector is hiding the extra variables! I hadn't noticed that Reflector did that before, so that's good to know!

Comment: So just to be clear: When I said *Release builds from Visual Studio definitely remove the extra variable*, well actually no they don't. `Resharper` removes it from the C# view, that's all that was happening.

Comment: s/ReSharper/Reflector/ -- JetBrains dotPeek shows the intermediate variables with names if there's a PDB file available; otherwise it does the same as Reflector -- remove the intermediates.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Ack darn it, yes my brain was thinking Reflector but my fingers betrayed me! ;